# Pagination and Sorting in cassandra using spring-data-cassandra

Tags: spring-data-cassandra

first of all, if any developper of the lib spring-data-cassandra read me : **Thank you** for your work, the lib is working like a charm and is well integrated to spring project.

Here is, a few days ago i was facing a problem when trying to use pagination in cassandra. I found a workaround to my problem and will explain how did i do that.

My problem is the following, i've been using pagination for cassandra and i've had to iterate over the slices of results and it worked until i decided to use Sort in pagination.

To achieve that i've used:
-a service using a Repository extending CassandraRepository

here is the code (the service wrapping the repository)

```
public Slice<Pony> getAllByTypePage(Pageable p, EnumType type) {
        Slice<Pony> slice = ponyRepository.findAllByType(p.first(), type);
        //Iterate over slices
        while(slice.hasNext()&&slice.getPageable().getPageNumber()<p.getPageNumber())
        {
            slice = ponyRepository.findAllByType(slice.nextPageable(), type);   
        }
        return slice;
    }
```

Pony is my Model en ponyRepository is my CassandraReposity

```
@Repository
public interface PonyRepository extends CassandraRepository<Pony,UUID> {

    @Async
    CompletableFuture<Long> countByType(EnumType type);

    Slice<Pony> findAllByType(Pageable p,EnumType type);
}
```

When i try to get a page (other than the first one) i get this exception

**com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.PagingStateException: Paging state mismatch, this means that either the paging state contents were altered, or you're trying to apply it to a different statement**

after some debugging i've seen that  the pageable object i obtained in the slice.nextPageable() was in Sort.UNSORTED mode instead of having the sort of my input pageable.

then, knowing that i made this workaround:

```
        public Slice<Pony> getAllByTypePage(Pageable p, EnumType type) {
        Slice<Pony> slice = ponyRepository.findAllByType(p.first(), type);
        //using a sidePageable and incrementing it in parallel
        Pageable sidePageable = p.first();
        //Iterate over slices
        while(slice.hasNext()&&sidePageable.getPageNumber()<p.getPageNumber())
        {
            CassandraPageRequest cpr = CassandraPageRequest.of(sidePageable.next(), ((CassandraPageRequest)slice.getPageable()).getPagingState());
            slice = ponyRepository.findAllByType(cpr, type);
            sidePageable=sidePageable.next();
        }
        return slice;
    }
```

the workaround seems to work.

**Is this behavior is normal or is it a bug?**

i have not seen any issues about this in the jira (maybe i did not looked at the good place).

here is the related libs i use (spring boot 2.2.1/spring code 5.2.1):

spring-data-cassandra : 2.2.1.RELEASE
cassandra-driver-core: 3.7.2

i have seen the same behavior on spring core 5.1.5

Best Regards

Comment: That looks like a bug. `SlicedExecution` does not consider sorting. Can you file a bug report at https://jira.spring.io.?

Comment: the issue https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACASS-700 have been created. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like said in the previous comments, it was a bug.
this is already fixed (see the issue linked before).

I just tried with the snapshot 2.2.2.BUILD-20191113.121102-4 and it seems to work.

for now i'll use my workaround. When the lib will be released i'll upgrade.

thanks for the help @mp911de